# Salersforce community theme: List-style CSS not working

Tags: community, css, html, community-builder

I am trying to implenent custom CSS into Salesforce communities. However, I've encountered an issue where list-style: none is not working, causing bullets to appear on a navbar.

This does not happen in a site created using LWR for example, however it does happen in the theme that we are trying to use, the Customer Service site with webster theme.

I can only assume this means there's something in the theme that is overwriting the custom CSS.

Any ideas on how to bypass the theme and enforce list-style: none?

Thanks.

Comment: The aura components are designed to use the CSS of its parent or container (the community template is the parent in this case).You can override the default style by adding some CSS to the Branding area of the community. (Click branding, and then edit the CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen a similar scenario in the past. This is working as designed behavior. The aura components are designed to use the CSS of its parent or container (the community template is the parent in this case).

You can override the default style by [adding some CSS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emergency_response_admin_communities_css.htm&type=5) to the Branding area of the experience site.

Example:

```
ol{
list-style: decimal
}

ul{
list-style: initial
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have found the CSS in question causing the issue and have overridden it successfully.